# Sets forming orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

So the question is:

Which of the following sets of vectors form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$
$(a) \{(1,0)^T, (0,1)^T\}$
$(b) \{(\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5})^T,(\frac{5}{13},\frac{12}{13})^T\}$

I know that a *is* a basis and b *is not*. The thing is, I just don't know **why**. I know the definition of orthonormal is if two vectors are perpendicular and of unit length. But I don't understand how to prove or even find for that matter, the orthonormal basis of a space. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are *orthogonal* if their dot product equals zero; that is
$$ x \cdot y = x_1 y_1 + \ldots + x_n y_n = 0,$$ 
where $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$. A vector $x$ is of unit length if $x \cdot x = 1$. A set is called *orthonormal* if every vector has unit length and any two different vectors are orthogonal. We also know the following:

> **Theorem**. If a set is orthonormal, then it is linearly independent.

So we can just compute the dot products between all the vectors in your examples, and check whether they equal 0 when dotting two different vectors, and equals 1 when dotting a vector with itself. Then, using the theorem, you'll automatically know whether it's a orthonormal basis or not.

Comment: Yah i just figured this out at the same time, thank you for the reply.

Comment: but how can you ensure that it spans the vector space??

Comment: @TheJoker, well if you know the set if orthonormal, then it's linearly independent, so you just count how many elements there are.

Answer (score 0):

Proving something to be orthonormal basis is simple. First prove the set of vector to be a basis (set is linear independent **and** set *spans* the vector space, here $\mathbb R^2$). Then check for orthogonal prperty, i.e dot product is $0$ and vectors are of unit length).

About your second question, please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process